# Is it possible to make voice call with normal fax modem?

Tags: phone-call, voice, modem

I have a 56K fax modem that should support voice, and should support full duplex. I need to make phone call, where i can play sound (out) , and also receive sound (in).

Procedures :
 -- I

```
nitializing modem
      AtQ0         ' Enables modem to send result codes to the DTE. 
      AT+GCI=B5    ' set country of installation to XX
      AT-STE=7     ' to be able to get busy , line in use messages
      AT+FCLASS=8  ' set mode to voice mode
      AT+VSM=130   ' set received audio format
 -- Dialing phone number
     ATD123456;   ' to dial number 123456
 -- WHAT IS NEXT 
 ??? I do assume that i have to read the data signals using VTR , but it gives me error since the modem is not into connect mode. If I used AT+VLS=1 , it will work well to get the audio data from line, but I can not then dial number (ATD1123456;)
```

Questions:
- What is the normal logic to start phone call , and record data.
- Shall I then read and write to the same COM Port, as this modem should support full duplex.? , or two different COM Ports are to be used?

Comment: The speed itself should be fine for some lower quality audio.

Comment: it should . i think. but how to initialize the call , and read audio ?

Comment: I mean what is the normal AT command sequence to make phone call , and be able to read and write audio data ?.

Comment: Check [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set) wikipedia article out.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is excellent. However, this is typical for recording incomping call. when i need is to start an voice call. The issue that I I have to dial number using ATD123456; , then use AT+VTR, but AT+VTR gives me error. If i used AT+VTR first, then modem starts sending audio data, but not able then to dial number